# Moq: how to verify a function that takes in a object created within a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following method;

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Repository UserRepository { get; set; }
    public void CreateUser(Message someMsg)
    {
       if (someMsg.CanCreate)
       {
           var obj = new object();
           UserRepository.Save(obj)
       }
    }
}
```

In my test case, I used Moq to mock out the ObjRepository and I wanted to to call verify on the "Save()" method.  However, the save method takes in a object that is created within the method under test, which I cannot mock.

Is there anyway around this using Moq?  I am doing this wrong?

Comment: yes, likely you are doing it wrong.  The DoStuff method should probably take the obj as a dependency.  You have obviously simplified your code for posting.  It would probably help for us to see real code .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have the following setup on your mock:

```
objRepMock.Setup(or => or.Save(It.IsAny<object>()).Callback(obj => {
   // Do asserts on the object here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

marcind got the ball rolling but I thought I'd put more code in. Your test would look like this:

```
var objMock = new Mock<Repository>();
objMock.Setup(x=>x.Save(It.IsAny<object>)).Verifiable();
var myclass = new MyClass{Repository = objMock.object};
var mymessage = new Mock<Message>();
myclass.CreateUser(mymessage.object);
objMock.Verify(x=>x.Save(It.IsAny<object>), Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use dependency injection.

```
public Repository ObjRepository { get; set;}
public void doStuff()
{
   var obj = new object();
   doStuff(obj);
}
public void doStuff(Object obj)
{
   ObjRepository.Save(obj)
}
```